# SMTP With gmail error. I'm not receiving the email

Tags: php

Is there something I'm missing? I've searched high, and low, and I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. Also is it that I'm using public, rather than mail?

```
    <?php
require_once('phpmailer.php');
class Mail extends PhpMailer
{
    // Set default variables for all new objects
    public $mail     = IsSMTP;   
    public $From     = 'register@lolvoid.net23.net';
    public $FromName = SITETITLE;
    public $Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    public $port     = 587;
    public $Mailer   = 'smtp';
    public $SMTPAuth = true;
    public $Username = 'email@gmail.com';
    public $Password = 'password';
    public $SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    public $WordWrap = 75;

    public function subject($subject)
    {
        $this->Subject = $subject;
    }

    public function body($body)
    {
        $this->Body = $body;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $this->AltBody = strip_tags(stripslashes($this->Body))."\n\n";
        $this->AltBody = str_replace("&nbsp;", "\n\n", $this->AltBody);
        return parent::send();
    }
}
```

This is my current code, and the issue hasn't been resolved. Any new ideas?

Comment: I have tried both 587, and 465.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351817/phpmailer-smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server)

Comment: you can't just use the gmail servers to spam people.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably a port.

```
 public $port     = '4587';
```

> if you tried configuring your SMTP server on port 465 (with SSL/TLS)
>   and port 587 (with STARTTLS), but are still having trouble sending
>   mail, try configuring your SMTP to use port 25 (with SSL/TLS).
>
> Apple Mail users: At times, Mail may misinterpret your SMTP server
>   settings. If you currently have 'smtp.gmail.com:username@gmail.com' in
>   the 'Outgoing Mail Server:' field of your settings, please try
>   changing the field to 'smtp.gmail.com' and saving your settings.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

You mixed 465 and 587 ports.

If it still does not work, you can try debugging connection. See [PHPMailer only sends email when SMTPDebug = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869269/phpmailer-only-sends-email-when-smtpdebug-true) for example.

Also, from documentation:

```
/**
 * SMTP class debug output mode.
 * Debug output level.
 * Options:
 * * `0` No output
 * * `1` Commands
 * * `2` Data and commands
 * * `3` As 2 plus connection status
 * * `4` Low-level data output
 * @var integer
 * @see SMTP::$do_debug
 */
public $SMTPDebug = 0;
```

Use it to find out what problem may be. It will tell you where it stops.

Comment: Fixed, But still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Port should be **587** instead of 4587.

Here are the default Gmail SMTP settings;

- Gmail SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com
- Gmail SMTP username: Your
  full Gmail address (e.g. yourusername@gmail.com)
- Gmail SMTP password: Your Gmail password
- Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587
- Gmail SMTP port (SSL): 465
- Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes

and could you please change the line

```
public $mail = 'IsSMTP()'
```

with the following:

```
public $mail = IsSMTP();
```

Comment: You're suggesting to send gmail credentials to smtp.mandrillapp.com ?

Comment: @zerkms I was mistaken about host.

Comment: Edited, and received no positive results

Comment: Did you try to change the line which I mentioned in my edited solution? @Jayy

Answer (score 0):

Change port to secured one for SMTP: 465